# Does every airport have a luggage locker?

Tags: air-travel, luggage

It may sound like a silly question but does every airport have a luggage locker?

I want to travel to Alicante (Spain) and I am wondering if there is any luggage locker where my notebook can fit.

I never used locker before so do you have information about Alicante?

Answer (score 3):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

By and large, most US airports [removed their luggage storage facilities](https://thepointsguy.com/guide/store-bags-at-the-airport/) after 9/11:

> Only a few US airports offer storage options these days and many are limited to 24 or 48 hours.  Whatever happened to storage lockers at airports? Terrorism. At many airports lockers were taken out after Sept. 11, 2001, and never replaced. Still, a few short-term storage options remain at some US airports.

The article lists a handful of major airports in the US that do still offer luggage storage services, and also suggests inquiring at the airport hotel.

Answer (score 2):

> every airport has luggage locker?

No, e.g. some tiny airports don't have it. Search to confirm if an airport has a luggage locker, e.g. yes for Alicante: https://www.google.com/search?q=alicante+airport+locker

Comment: Although according to https://www.aena.es/en/alicante-elche/airport-services/shops-and-restaurants/pv21.html&p=1575045836063&t=nt (the official airport website) the left luggage facility is currently closed.

Comment: @dunni thanks, how about the right one?

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. What I understand from their website. Right one is working and location shown on website.

Comment: If I'm understanding the website correctly, it is not a left/right directional thing: the service of leaving your luggage in storage ("left luggage") is currently closed. You may want to contact the airport (the website lists the phone number (+34) 91 321 1000 at the bottom) to confirm that it's still closed and to ask if they have any suggested alternatives.